# Crash report for iOS app

Tags: support, ios-app

The Stack Exchange iOS app crashed during some user action. How I can send a crash report (and where I can find it) to the developer team?

Or was a crash report sent automatically in the background? How can I be sure? Which steps do I need to do to help the develop team after the app crashed?

Comment: @rene I know that I need to ask a question on Meta.SE when I found a bug in the app. My question is about crash dumps in general.

Comment: did you read the answer? It says *Crash reports are automatically reported back to us* which is taken from the help.

Comment: @rene oops, sorry. I did.

Comment: Unless there are different crash reports  but  I'm not that much into iOS telemetry.